# autofill combobox based on another combo box selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am autofilling second textbox based on first textbox in auto.jsp, similarly i want to autofill a combobox, how can i do it? that is autofill second combo box based on first combo box selection. 
------auto.jsp-------

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
    var xmlHttp  
    var xmlHttp
    function showState(str){ 
        if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined"){
            xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else if (window.ActiveXObject){
            xmlHttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        if (xmlHttp==null){
            alert ("Browser does not support XMLHTTP Request")
            return
        } 
        var url="state.jsp";
        url += "?count=" +document.getElementById("textbox1").value;//passing first textbox value and displaying in textbox2 ID
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChange;
        xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
    function stateChange(){   
        if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){   
            document.getElementById("textbox2").value = xmlHttp.responseText;    
        }   
    }   
</script>  
 <body>  
 <input id="textbox1" type="text" name="name" onkeyup="showState(this.value)"/> 
<input id="textbox2" type="text" name="secondVal" />// here i am displaying first textbox value
</body>
```

--------state.jsp-----------

```
<%
String firsttextbox=request.getParameter("count");//Got first textbox value
out.println(firsttextbox);// setting it in second text box value by document.getElementById("textbox2").value = xmlHttp.responseText; 
%>
```

**Same thing i want to do when a drop down is selected from first combo box, then an event will be fired to state.jsp there by enabling second combo box in auto.jsp, how can i achieve it?**

Thanks

Comment: Are you doing an Ajax request just to set a textbox to the same value as another textbox? Or is this just a simplified example and really the second textbox's value will come from a database lookup based on the first value?

Comment: no i am not doing an ajax request, this is just a simplified example that is second textbox's value will come from a database lookup based on the first value . Similarly i want that a combo box will be populated based on another combo box selection. I found that in all browsers ajax is not supported.

Comment: @nnnnnn how can i do it? please suggest an answer

Comment: You _are_ doing an Ajax request, that's what all that `XMLHttpRequest` stuff in your code is about. Answer posted...

Comment: please see my comments below if possible please provide me a solution nnnnnn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your existing code a *lot* if you use jQuery - which I assume you do from the way you tagged your question. The following would replace all of the code you showed, plus you wouldn't need the inline `onkeyup` in your html:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#textbox1").keyup(function() {
      $.get('state.jsp', {count : this.value}, function(responseData) {
         $("#textbox2").val(responseData);
      });
   });
});
```

Where [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) is one of jQuery's simple Ajax methods. It passes the data from the second parameter to the url in the first parameter, and when a response comes back it calls the function in the third parameter (which is kind of equivalent to your `stateChange()` function except jQuery tests the state for you and only calls the function when ready).

(By the way, I wouldn't recommend a new Ajax request on every keyup. Maybe do it on blur, or at least use a timeout mechanism to only do an event when the user has stopped typing for, say, 400ms.)

When you say "autofill second combo box based on first combo box selection" do you mean set the list of available options depending on the value selected in the first combo? Assuming you do you can use a technique similar to the above:

```
$("#combo1,#combo2,#combo3").change(function() {
   var associatedCombo = $(this).attr('data-associated');
       requestData = {};
   requestData[this.id] = $(this).val();
   $.get('combo.jsp', requestData, function(responseData) {
      $("#" + associatedCombo).replaceWith(responseData);
   });
});

<select id="combo1" data-associated="combo4">
```

Where `'combo.jsp'` would process the 'combo1Val' request parameter and return the appropriate data. If you use the [`.replaceWith()` method](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) it would need to return the HTML for the filled combo something like this:

```
<select id="combo2" name="combo2">
   <option value="1">One</option>
   ...
</select>
```

Because the entire existing combo would be replaced with the new one. Of course there are lots of other approaches, e.g., returning just the options, or returning JSON and using it to create the options one by one.

Comment: ya it worked...thanks a lot nnnnnn, but when i am selecting first combo box then inside 2nd combo box id that combo.jsp is loaded but how to populate that 2nd combo box?

Comment: similarly if two or more comboboxes will be there then i have to make separate jsp pages for each onchange event?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're asking in your second comment. If it "worked" then isn't it populating? As far as making separate jsp pages for each, you can do it all with one jsp if you include a request parameter to tell it what type of information you are requesting and have it only return the appropriate thing.

Comment: ok ok...by request parameter can you please edit your code so that i can send both text box id and combo box id, i was trying but could not get it

Comment: @nnnnnn...please help me by editing your code so that i can send multiple combo box value to one jsp page

Comment: If you can tell me what request parameters you want your jsp to handle I can probably update the jQuery code in my answer to set them. What are the parameters to be called, and what values should they have?

Comment: ok 3 combo boxes and combo1, combo2, combo3 are their ids to be sent to combo.jsp by onchange event when called and combo4, combo5, combo6 are the ids where i will get response from combo1, combo2, combo3 respectively, so total 6 combo boxes are in auto.jsp

Comment: OK, edited. Update your first three combos to add a `data-associated="comboX"` attribute (where "X" is the number of the associated combo), and then the updated code will create a request parameter with the same name as the combo id that was changed.

Comment: i am doing wrong somewhere please see this code: $("#combo1,#combo2,#combo3").change(function() {
   var associatedCombo = $(this).attr('data-associated');
       requestData = {};
   requestData[this.id] = $(this).val();
   $.get('combo.jsp', requestData, function(responseData) {
      $("combo4#" + associatedCombo).replaceWith(responseData);
       $("combo5#" + associatedCombo).replaceWith(responseData);
        $("combo6#" + associatedCombo).replaceWith(responseData);
   });
});          like this?

Comment: i faced a problem here: i am showing data on 2nd textbox based on 1st textbox, but in state.jsp, i want to write something(different value from 2nd textbox) that will be displayed on 3rd textbox on response by onkeyup event in 1st text box. How can i do it?