# Fill list from different table based on primary id

Tags: php, javascript

I have 3 table which have relation with each others... In 1st table, i have student details contains studentid (PK), studentname, dob, etc...

Table 2 contain course consist of coursecodeid(PK), studentid(FK), coursename, teachername and etc..

Table 3 contain grade consist of studentid(fk), courseid(fk), id(pk_autoincrement) and grade.

When system starts, studentid will be load into a dropmenu. Onchange this dropmenu, second dropmenu will be shown and load with courseid take by selected student (based on studentid)

When user select courseid onchange a label will be visible to show student grade.

Everything done in 1 page... Anybody can give me sample code either in php or javascript since i am using php and mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax. That is the way to go. Check [here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) for ideas, this is doing something similar to what you are trying to achieve. Check [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more abstract code reference. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187971/autofill-combobox-based-on-another-combo-box-selection) is a possible duplicate. And generally, searching for `loading combobox based on other combobox jquery` will give you pretty decent results.